# Proof of Cauchy's Beta Integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{(1+it)^x(1-it)^y}$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

The Cauchy's Beta Integral is given by

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dt}{(1+it)^x(1-it)^y}=\frac{\pi 2^{2-x-y}\Gamma(x+y-1)}{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}$$

I would like to know how it is proved.

Comment: I'm not familiar with complex analysis, could you explain me how to interpret $(1+it)^x$ for $x=1/2$, $t=1$ (for example). It seems to me that this expression is multivalued, so your integral is not well defined.

Comment: You may read this paper: http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~kisilv/courses/sp-funct.pdf section 1.4.2

Comment: The proof is given in @ShaneChern link on page 8.

Comment: see also here: http://de.wikibooks.org/wiki/Formelsammlung_Mathematik:_Bestimmte_Integrale:_Form_R%28x%29#Vier_Parameter, example **4.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{1 + \ic t}^{x}\pars{1 - \ic t}^{y}}
     =2^{2 - x - y}\,\pi\,
     {\Gamma\pars{x + y - 1} \over \Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y}}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{1 + \ic t}^{x}\pars{1 - \ic t}^{y}}}
> =-\ic\int_{-\infty\ic}^{\infty\ic}{\dd t \over \pars{1 + t}^{x}\pars{1 - t}^{y}}
> \\[3mm]&=\ic\int_{-\infty}^{-1}
> {\dd t \over \verts{1 + t}^{x}\expo{\ic\pi x}\pars{1 - t}^{y}}
> +\ic\int_{-1}^{-\infty}
> {\dd t \over \verts{1 + t}^{x}\expo{-\ic\pi x}\pars{1 - t}^{y}}
> \\[3mm]&=\ic\expo{-\ic\pi x}\int_{1}^{\infty}
> {\dd t \over \verts{1 - t}^{x}\pars{1 + t}^{y}}
> -\ic\expo{\ic\pi x}\int_{1}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \verts{1 - t}^{x}\pars{1 + t}^{y}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\ic\pars{\expo{\ic\pi x} - \expo{-\ic\pi x}}
> \int_{1}^{\infty}{\pars{t - 1}^{-x} \over \pars{1 + t}^{y}}\,\dd t
> =2^{1 - y}\sin\pars{\pi x}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {t^{-x} \over \pars{1 + t/2}^{y}}\,\dd t
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#c00000}{%
> 2^{2 - x - y}\sin\pars{\pi x}\int_{0}^{\infty}
> {t^{-x} \over \pars{1 + t}^{y}}\,\dd t}
> \end{align}

With $\ds{\xi \equiv {1 \over 1 + t}\quad\imp\quad t = {1 \over \xi} - 1}$:
\begin{align}&\color{#c00000}{%
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{1 + \ic t}^{x}\pars{1 - \ic t}^{y}}}
=2^{2 - x - y}\sin\pars{\pi x}
\int_{1}^{0}\pars{{1 \over \xi} - 1}^{-x}\xi^{y}\,\pars{-\,{\dd\xi \over \xi^{2}}}
\\[3mm]&=2^{2 - x - y}\sin\pars{\pi x}
\int_{1}^{0}\xi^{x + y - 2}\pars{1 - \xi}^{-x}\,\dd\xi
=2^{2 - x - y}\sin\pars{\pi x}\
\overbrace{{\rm B}\pars{x + y - 1,-x + 1}}^{\ds{\mbox{Beta Function}}}
\\[3mm]&=2^{2 - x - y}\sin\pars{\pi x}\
\overbrace{{\Gamma\pars{x + y - 1}\Gamma\pars{-x + 1}\over \Gamma\pars{y}}}
^{\ds{\Gamma's:\ \mbox{Gamma Functions}}}
\end{align}

> With *Euler Reflection Formula*:
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{-x + 1} = {\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi x}\Gamma\pars{x}}}$ such that
>   $$\color{#44f}{\large%
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\dd t \over \pars{1 + \ic t}^{x}\pars{1 - \ic t}^{y}}
> =2^{2 - x - y}\,\pi\,
> {\Gamma\pars{x + y - 1} \over \Gamma\pars{x}\Gamma\pars{y}}}
> $$
>   where
>   $$
> \Re\pars{x} < 1\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad\Re\pars{x + y} > 1
> $$